RateLimitError: openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details
Even Though I have added balance in my OpenAI Account I am unable to use OpenAI user Key / Project Key.
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",  
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Hey"}
    ],
    max_tokens=5
)
print(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'].strip())```

This is what I am Trying to Implement.
I am getting
raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.
Please give me the solution regarding, how to solve this even Though I have sufficient balance credit inside my OpenAI account.

This question is similar to: OpenAI API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
